# Convert a json (with many levels) into a List c#

Tags: c#, json, .net, generics, collections

I have a JSON with many levels inside it like below

```
{
    "value": [
        {
            "CityId": 100
            "Colleges": {
                "CollegeName": "ABC",
                "Departments": [
                    {
                        "DepartmentId": 1001,
                        "DepartmentInfo": {
                            "Name": "ComputerScience",
                            "StudentsCount": 60,
                            "HOD": "John"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "DepartmentId": 1002,
                        "DepartmentInfo": {
                            "Name": "Humanties",
                            "StudentsCount": 120,
                            "HOD": "Ravi"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "CityId": 100
            "Colleges": {
                "CollegeName": "DEF",
                "Departments": [
                    {
                        "DepartmentId": 2001,
                        "DepartmentInfo": {
                            "Name": "ComputerScience",
                            "StudentsCount": 60,
                            "HOD": "James"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "DepartmentId": 2002,
                        "DepartmentInfo": {
                            "Name": "Humanties",
                            "StudentsCount": 120,
                            "HOD": "Donald"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I have take info like CollegeInfo, DepartmentId, Name,StudentsCount,HOD. So I have created the class with these properties.

Now from the below code I am able to fetch all the info inside a Dictionary<string, object>. Here the Key is the path of the property inside the JSON.

```
private static void FillDictionaryFromJToken(Dictionary<string, object> dict, JToken token, string path = "")
        {
            switch (token.Type)
            {
                case JTokenType.Object:
                    foreach (JProperty prop in token.Children<JProperty>())
                    {
                        FillDictionaryFromJToken(dict, prop.Value, prop.Path);
                    }
                    break;

                case JTokenType.Array:
                    foreach (JToken value in token.Children())
                    {
                        FillDictionaryFromJToken(dict, value);
                    }
                    break;

                default:
                    dict.Add(path, ((JValue)token).Value);
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Now all the properties of the first set are seperate records and so as second set. The paths will be like  this [0].Colleges.Departments[0].DepartmentId, Colleges.Departments[0].DepartmentInfo.Name etc.
But I want to fill these info in the class as a single record with all the properties in that record and same as for 2nd set.

Any help??

Comment: Are there any particular reason not to parse it into class structure (using only needed properties) and then map it into desired one?

Comment: are u talking abt to create an exact class structure of this json and then parse it? yes this json contains less properties as compared to actual one I have to work on and i dont need all the properties in the json

Comment: Then skip properties you don't need but preserve the hierarchy. You can use https://app.quicktype.io/ and remove not needed properties from generated classes.

Comment: I dont want to restrict it with a class since there can be some other jsons  as well with different properties

Comment: I would say "Not restricting to classes" does not give anything in this context, cause you still need to understand which path should go where.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the package Newtonsoft.Json, and use the code:

```cs
YourClassWithTheProperties instance = 
    JsonConvert.Deserialize<YourClassWithTheProperties>(jsonString);
```

Doing this you'll have a class and you can use the foreach in the properties.

Comment: Why not `System.Text.Json`?

Comment: Well, I don't know how to use it, I only used the Newtonsoft.Json.